# Javascript - return value from a loop

Tags: javascript, return

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  var odd = 0;
  A.forEach(num => {
    A.forEach(num2 => {
      if (num == num2) {
        odd = odd + 1;
      };
    });

    if (odd % 2 == 1) {
      console.log("num = " + num);
      return num;
    }
    odd = 0;
  });
}

var result = findOdd([5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]);

console.log(result);
```

When I try to return num, it is returning as undefined. And if I remove the "return" statement it is printing correctly to the console.

Comment: `forEach` ignores its callback's `return` value. `Array.prototype.forEach` iterates over every array item unconditionally, you cannot stop mid-way. In this case there is no reason to not use a good old `for` loop.

Comment: With the return the final assignment of “odd = 0” is skipped in some cases which also affects the behavior of subsequent code.

Comment: Are you just trying to filter the odd numbers from your array, or something more?

Comment: In `forEach` it ignores `return` value as well as in `for` loop the `return` statement breaks the loop once it is executed. Therefore consider putting the `return` statement outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't break out of forEach using return and return it. You are not returning anything from your function as return from foreach does not get returned.

You can use for loop to do this.

```js
function findOdd(A) {
  var odd = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
      if (A[i] == A[j]) {
        odd = odd + 1;
      }
    }

    if (odd % 2 == 1) {
      console.log("num = " + A[i]);
      return A[i];
    }
    odd = 0;
  }

}

var result = findOdd([5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]);

console.log(result);
```